# find a string in log file and search another string after the first string

Tags: string, autoit

i have a unique id in placed in a log file, i can search the file and get to it, once i find the unique id in the file i need to find another string (naming it string 2)  after this unique id and copy the very next line of the string 2 .

Please find below my function and please suggest how to achieve this .

```
Func getAuthResponse($LogfilePath, $AuthRespFilePath, $UniqueId, $search)

Global $iLine = 0, $sLine = ''
Global $hFile = FileOpen($LogfilePath)

If $hFile = -1 Then
MsgBox(0,'ERROR','Unable to open file for reading.')
Exit 1
EndIf    ;If $hFile = -1 Then

; find the line that has the search string
While 1
$iLine += 1
$sLine = FileReadLine($hFile)

If @error = -1 Then ExitLoop
  ; finding the unique id in the log file

  ;ConsoleWrite($UniqueId & @LF)
  If StringInStr($sLine, $UniqueId) Then
     ConsoleWrite($sLine & @LF)
     ; assuming that unique id is found , now finding the phrase Auth response is as follow : after the unique id
     $sNewLine = $sLine+
     If StringInStr($sLine, $search) Then
        ConsoleWrite($sLine & @LF)

       //// SOME LOGIC ////

     ExitLoop
     EndIf        ;If StringInStr($sLine, $search) Then

  ExitLoop
  EndIf        ;If(StringInStr($sLine, $UniqueId) Then

WEnd        ;While 1
FileClose($hFile)
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets see if I understood that correctly:

You need to find an ID, afther this ID a string and after that you need to copy the next line. If that's correct, I made you a new `While` Loop, it's just a `For` Loop now.

```
#include <File.au3>
For $c1 = 1 To _FileCountLines($hFile) Step +1
    $sLine = FileReadLine($hFile, $c1)
    If (StringInStr($sLine, $UniqueId) > 0) Then
        For $c2 = $c1 To _FileCountLines($hFile) Step +1
            $sLine = FileReadLine($hFile, $c2)
            If (StringInStr($sLine, $search) > 0) Then
                $LINE_AFTER_STRING_2 = FileReadLine($hFile, $c2 + 1)
                ExitLoop
            EndIf
        Next
    EndIf
Next

If $LINE_AFTER_STRING_2 = "" Then MsgBox(0, "NOT FOUND", "NOT FOUND")
```

Following things happen: First it loops through all lines and searches for your ID, if it finds it, it starts a new For Loop and searches for your string after the ID, if it finds that one it counts +1 to the line and reads it. This should be the line you are looking for. The variable is called `$LINE_AFTER_STRING_2`, feel free to change that.

Don't forget to include the File.au3 because i used `_FileCountLines`

Comment: Thats not very helpful. What doesn't work? Which code does error. This code is not tested and I just made it really quick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <File.au3>

Func getAuthResponse($LogfilePath, $UniqueId, $search)

    Local $arrayFile = ""
    Local $output    = ""

    If Not FileExists($LogfilePath) Then Return SetError(1, 0, -1)

    _FileReadToArray($LogfilePath, $arrayFile)

    For $i = 1 To $arrayFile[0]
        If StringInStr($arrayFile[$i], $UniqueId) Then
            For $j = $i+1 To $arrayFile[0]
                If StringInStr($arrayFile[$j], $search) Then
                    $output = $arrayFile[$j+1]
                    ExitLoop
                EndIf
            Next
            ExitLoop
        EndIf       
    Next

    Return $output

EndFunc
```